# There is no row at position 0 query

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am new to C# and .NET and I am struggling with some code that is throwing a error, the error it throws is:

```
There is no row at position 0.
```

Here is my code that I got, as far as I can see if the sql returs 0 rows the 404 should be displayed, however at the moment I am getting a stack error.

This is the stack error:

```
[IndexOutOfRangeException: There is no row at position 0.]
System.Data.RBTree`1.GetNodeByIndex(Int32 userIndex) +2409382
System.Data.DataRowCollection.get_Item(Int32 index) +20
Targetting.ArticlePage.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\SRC\Site1\Web\Article\Trunk\Article.aspx.cs:78
CommonBasePageClass.BaseWebPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +50
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3178
```

Here is the code that I believe is throwing the error:

```
//If the article is Archived or Unknown or has expired then all users should be shown an "unavailable" message instead of the content
if (dt.Rows[0]["pagestatusid"].ToString() == "3" || dt.Rows[0]["pagestatusid"].ToString() == "0" || (dt.Rows[0]["expirydate"] != DBNull.Value && DateTime.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["expirydate"].ToString()) < DateTime.Now))
{
    pnlDraftWarning.Visible = false;
    pnlContentNotAvailable.Visible = true;
    pnlMainContent.Visible = false;

    Response.StatusCode = 404;
    return;
}
```

Comment: Your DataTable `dt` contains no data.

Comment: Maybe there is actually no row at position 0?

Comment: You can use `if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)` to check it. But have you loaded the `DataTable` at all? Show that code.

Comment: Why someone downvoted the question?

Comment: @SeraphimFoA Probably because it shows no effort in own investigation?

Answer (score 4):

The error is that there is no data at row zero - the table `dt` is empty.

The code is expecting there to be atleast one row

```
if (dt.Rows[0]["pagestatusid"].ToString() == "3" || dt.Rows[0]["pagestatusid"].ToString() == "0" || (dt.Rows[0]["expirydate"] != DBNull.Value && DateTime.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["expirydate"].ToString()) < DateTime.Now))
{
}
```

You can work around this issue by adding a guard condition to check if there is data.

```
if (dt == null ||
    dt.Rows.Count < 1 ||
    dt.Rows[0]["pagestatusid"].ToString() == "3" ||
    dt.Rows[0]["pagestatusid"].ToString() == "0" ||
    (dt.Rows[0]["expirydate"] != DBNull.Value &&
     DateTime.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["expirydate"].ToString()) < DateTime.Now))
{
  // other code
}
```

or identify the reason why there might not be data when you are expecting there to be some.

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is any rows:

```
if (
       dt.Rows.Count()>0 && 
       (
           dt.Rows[0]["pagestatusid"].ToString() == "3" || 
           dt.Rows[0]["pagestatusid"].ToString() == "0" || 
           (
               dt.Rows[0]["expirydate"] != DBNull.Value && 
               DateTime.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["expirydate"].ToString()) < DateTime.Now
           )
       )
   )
{
    pnlDraftWarning.Visible = false;
    pnlContentNotAvailable.Visible = true;
    pnlMainContent.Visible = false;

    Response.StatusCode = 404;
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use **either**

```
if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
```

**or**

```
if(dt == null)
```